# "CUNEIFORM SIGN LUGAL" is displayed just as rectangle. How can I fix it?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

On [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/12217/browsertest.htm) or [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Sumerian/Grammar/Lesson_One_-_The_Plural_Marker) in Wikibooks on Sumerian, there are lot of missing characters, where only rectangles are displayed instead.

How can I fix it? I would like to see those characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Trusty Tahr here is a nice font package that will allow you to see these characters:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
```

I tested this on my own Trusty Tahr installation and below is a screenshot showing success on one page:

[image]

and also success on the other:

[image]

And hopefully also success on your system :)

**Notes:**

- *After* Trusty Tahr the package `ttf-ancient-fonts` becomes a *transitional package* for the package `fonts-ancient-scripts`.

Comment: ... works perfectly on Ubuntu 17.10. Thank you!

Comment: That... looks really messy, especially the first one. Are you certain that it's a success?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, it's supposed to look like that. It's wider than most Unicode characters. Cf. [Arabic ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Word_ligatures)